# Starting any activity on the system

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to allow a user to supply a class name and then launch the `Activity` but I keep getting an error stating:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.intel.ave.androidclient/com.android.vending}; have you declared this Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I haven't placed it in my Manifest as I won't know what the user wants at runtime.

```
//package_name = input from the user
//MyContext = the activity context
Intent newprocess = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
newprocess.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
newprocess.setClassName(MyContext, package_name);
MyContext.startActivity(newprocess );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting an external activity with an intent is a bit different than starting within your app. See [calling activity from external Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842387/calling-activity-from-external-activity). Quoting from there, you would use this instead

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.the.other.app");
startActivity(intent);
```