# I want to start an apk from my Qt under Android application(Neccesitas sdk)

Tags: android, qt, qprocess

My goal is to start an apk already installed on my Android device when pressing a button from my application written in Qt under Andoird(Neccesitas sdk).
In Qt under Windows this was done simply by using QProcess like:

```
m_processP = new QProcess;
m_processP->start ( "somthing.exe" );
.....
```

But on Android it seems that it does not work like that.
I'm trying also with QProcess...start("Settings.apk") but i always got the error: ProcessError::FailedToStart.
Has somebody encountered the same issues like me?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Uh, googled through the tons of resources here and on Qt forum finally puzzled a solution from many sources to run an application:

### C++ code:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void start(const QString &packageName)
{
    QAndroidJniObject javaPackageName = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(packageName);
    bool success = (bool)QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jboolean>(
                "com/mycompany/myapp/PackageActivity",
                "runApplication",
                "(Ljava/lang/String;)Z",
                javaPackageName.object<jstring>());

    if(!success) {
        qDebug() << "Error:" << packageName << "package not found!";
    }
}
```

### Java code:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;

public class PackageActivity
{
    public static boolean runApplication(String packageName)
    {
        Activity activity = org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative.activity();
        PackageManager pm = activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (intent != null) {
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Main problems were

- to get working `Activity` object
- and then call `getPackageManager()` on proper object as method was
  returning following error to me called on arbitrary created `Acivity` and `Context` objects:

> `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 1):

Things are not so simple on Android. You have to know package and an `Activity` names you want to run (on Android "application" consists of Activities, and you can only display them, not "run"). You must do it via JNI call (from C++ to Java), and try to start an instance of desired Activity from there. It's a bit complex.

Read more about starting entry activity from other app [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842387/calling-activity-from-external-activity), ans about JNI calls [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_NDK.html).

Comment: Thank you, I have access to package and activity. I'll investigate JNI, I thought that QT portability makes it easier to use processes independent of platform.

Comment: It's not about Qt, it's about how Android is designed - in general, the application lifecycle is very different on mobile devices (i. e. you can have two "applications" running in the same process) - you just have to accept it and follow the Android guidelines.