# How do I replicate the following intent in Qt 6.5.0?

Tags: android, qt, android-intent, qt6

This intent works and does what I want on Android.

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat= 
[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
cmp=SOB.Bacon/com.backend.RunBackend }
```

I want to create an equivalent intent for Qt 6.5.0 on Android.

What would the code for this look like? I have been looking through the Qt documentation and the sample code is not making it clear how to do this.

This is the exact intent that ADB uses to start the service that I am trying to start on Android, so if ADB can do it from the computer then Qt should be able to do it.

And for reference this is the ADB command that I ran which produced this intent info.

```
adb shell am startforegroundservice 
SOB.Bacon/com.backend.RunBackend
```

I tried using just startservice but it wouldn't do it as it was in the background.

**EDIT 1**

I found an interesting link:

[I want to start an apk from my Qt under Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428596/i-want-to-start-an-apk-from-my-qt-under-android-applicationneccesitas-sdk)

Is this the only way to do this? Seems to me like there should be a way to do it directly from Qt.